# Python Regex Remove the word with \

Tags: python, regex

I am doing sentiment analysis on tweets, during preprocessing of data some pesky items like \xe2\x9c\x8c\ pops up I was using Regex to remove the rest like # tags, etc. But can't remove these items.

What I want to do is select the word starting with \ and replace it with ''.

```
text = re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '', text)  # removes the @
text = re.sub(r'#', '', text)  # removes the hashtags
text = re.sub(r'RT[\s]+', '', text)  # removes RT
text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/\S+', '', text)  # removes hyperlinks

# text=re.sub(r'\\.*$', '', text)
```

My other regular expressions are above.

I also tried using python but it also doesn't work

```
filter(lambda x:x[0]!='\/', text.split())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if thats what you mean but this should work

```
re.sub('\\\\\\S+','','some normal text,#slash/ #backslash\\ \\backslashedtext back to normal')
```

Returns

```
'some normal text,#slash/ #backslash\\  back to normal'
```

Why?

Because by simply passing '\\' as a first argument you create backslash in python string so it gets passed through to the regex parser but it understands it as a single backslash so an escape character.

When you pass '\\\\' regex parser gets '\\' and thus searches for '\'

So passing '\\\\\\S+' regex parser gets '\\\S+' and searches for '\' proceded by more than one "not whitespace"

As a side note
"\xe2\x9c\x8c" looks like hex numbers so '\\\\x[0-9a-f]{2}' regex pattern will match the whole thing